# Cauchy sequence real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, education, cauchy-sequences

Prove that if a sequence $X_n$ is Cauchy, then the sequence $X^2_n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have not triedi think its so difficult and complicated

Comment: Start with the definition, perhaps, and write out what you need to show in terms of that definition.

Comment: How do you know it's difficult if you didn't even try? For sure you know something, at least the definitions.

Comment: Uh. Maybe you should go back and review what you do not understand before attempting to do this problem, then.

Comment: @SaraKanan I'd start by writing out the definition of Cauchiness, when applied to $X_n$. Have you proven that Cauchy sequences are bounded?

Comment: I stucked with the second part

Comment: How can i write out the defintion of cauchy for the $X^2_n$

Comment: I want to know how could i wrote what i need to prove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemma: A Cauchy sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$is bounded. Proof: Let $\nu$ be such that $|a_s-a_t|<1$ whenever $s,t \ge \nu.$ Thus, for $s \ge \nu,$ $$|a_s-a_{\nu}|<1$$ $$a_{\nu}-1<a_s< a_{\nu}+1$$ $$|a_s|<\max(|a_{\nu}-1|,| a_{\nu}+1|)$$
$$\text {Let }K=\max(|a_1|,…,|a_{\nu -1}|,|a_{\nu}-1|,| a_{\nu}+1|)$$ Thus $|a_s| \le K$ for all $s$, proving the lemma.Now we can prove that the sequence of squares is also Cauchy. Let $\epsilon>0.$ Let $p$ be such that $|a_m-a_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2K}$wnever $m,n \ge p.$. Then, for $m,n \ge p,$
$$|a_m^2-a_n^2|=|a_m-a_n||a_m+a_n|$$ $$\le |a_m-a_n|(|a_m|+|a_n|)$$
$$<\frac{\epsilon}{2K}(K+K)=\epsilon,Q.E.D.$$

Comment: Oh i forgetted that every cauchy is bounded. Thank you so much.